# Using Geotools raster layer in Geomajas web application

Tags: java, geotools, geomajas

I am working on a Geomajas web application and have a Geotools RasterLayer (a GridReaderLayer to be precise) that needs to be integrated with the map in the Geomajas app.

I have been searching the web for quite a while now but didn't find anything really useful.

If this can be done, then how do I get started?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at the details, but it should be possible to implement a RasterLayer which displays GeoTools rasters.

You could have a look at some of the other raster layers as example (the WMS layer is probably a good example).